# Match number with variable number of digits

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to determine if a string matches a regular expression pattern:

```
expected = re.compile(r'session \d+: running')
string = "session 1234567890: running"
re.match(expected, string)
```

However, `re.match()` always returns `None`. Am I trying to match the decimals incorrectly? The number should be 10 digits but I would like to cover the case that it is more or less digits.

EDIT: The string parameter is actually a result of a previous match:

```
expected = re.compile(r'session \d+: running')
found = re.match(otherRegex, otherString)
re.match(expected, found.groups()[0])
```

When I print the type of `found.groups()[0]` it prints `class str` and when I print `found.groups()[0]`, it prints the string I expect: `"session 1234567890: running"`. Could this be why it is not working for me?

Comment: are you sure that this is the content of your string. Because it works for me just fine.

Comment: ... [same for me](http://codepad.org/Sl1DLQiV)

Comment: You preferably should not use string as variable name

Comment: works fine for me.  As a matter of style, it's probably better to use `expected.match(string)`

Comment: @SilentGhost -- I tested my version of it -- I just assumed that OP's version *didn't work* since there was a question about it (and that was the best explanation I could come up with)

Comment: RE `found.groups()[0]`: You should really use `found.group(1)` for that.

Comment: @Kreuzade: are you sure that the content of `found.groups()[0]` is not tab-separated or some such?

Comment: @SilentGhost I am not certain how to make sure it is not tab-separated...

Comment: @SilentGhost That gives me the string I expect surrounded by single quotes.

Comment: @Kreuzade: could you try `re.search` instead of `re.match`?

Comment: @SilentGhost I found my mistake and managed to answer my own question. I guess from now on I shouldn't try to shorten things in my question. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my question I had shortened the string to the parts that were relevant. The actual string had:

```
expected = re.compile(r'session \d+: running task(s)')
str = "session 1234567890: running(s)"
re.match(expected, str)
```

The reason there were never matches is because the `'('` and `')'` characters are special characters and I needed to escape them. The code is now:

```
expected = re.compile(r'session \d+: running task\(s\)')
str= "session 1234567890: running(s)"
re.match(expected, str)
```

Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

**No** it doesn't, it works fine for me:

```
In [219]: strs = "session 1234567890: running"

In [220]: expected = re.compile(r'session \d+: running')

In [221]: x=re.match(expected, strs)

In [222]: x.group()
Out[222]: 'session 1234567890: running'
```